# External component has thrown an exception from third party application

Tags: c#, winforms, crash

I'm currently developing my software for machine automation and integrating a third party application "Visionscape" with my project in Visual Studio.

However, when it comes to applying the function of
**shareMem.frmVSKit.JobLoad(path, "SoftSys1");** , my whole software crash and popup an error of "External component has thrown an exception".

Any solution to encounter this issue??

P/S: **shareMem.frmVSKit.JobLoad(path, "SoftSys1");** is a function from the third party application.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O14ri.jpg)

Comment: Share your code and stacktrace please.

Comment: @Berkay Hi, thanks for replying and the image of the error code has been updated above.